# Multiple click events on one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/rHVcX/1/

Is it possible to have multiple click events on one elements, when using different selectors?

```
<button id="test" class="testclass">test</button>
<button id="test2" class="testclass2">test 2</button>

//only B
$('.testclass')[0].click(function(){alert('A');});
$('#test').click(function(){alert('B');});

// A and B
$('#test2').click(function(){alert('A2');});
$('#test2').click(function(){alert('B2');});
```

Comment: `$('.testclass')[0]` will give you the DOM element, not a jQuery object. It should be `$('.testclass').eq(0)` or just `$('.testclass')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly possible.

However, you're misusing jQuery.
Writing `$(...)[0]` gives you the first *raw DOM element* in the set.
It isn't a jQuery object, so you can't call jQuery's `click` method on it.

Instead, you should call the `eq` method, which returns a jQuery object containing a single element from the original set.

Change it to `$('.testclass').eq(0).click(...)`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

However, this line:

```
$('.testclass')[0].click(function(){alert('A');});
```

Will not work. It should be:

```
$('.testclass').eq(0).click(function(){alert('A');});
```

Indexing the jQuery object will give you the DOM element at index zero, not a filtered jQuery object.

http://api.jquery.com/eq

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have multiple click events on the object. The handlers wil be called in the order they were added (unless you say `return false` in one of them).

Answer (score 0):

remove `[0]` or change it to `.eq(0)`

```
<button id="test" class="testclass">test</button>
<button id="test2" class="testclass2">test 2</button>

//only B
$('.testclass').click(function(){alert('A');});
$('#test').click(function(){alert('B');});

// A and B
$('#test2').click(function(){alert('A2');});
$('#test2').click(function(){alert('B2');});
```

working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rHVcX/2/